# Trouble with datetime in python2.7/django1.5.1

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm trying to get the number of days in between the current date and a fixed date set in the past.

```
from datetime import *

past = date(2013, 1, 1)
now = datetime.now()

print now - past
```

When I run this, I get:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`datetime.date()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) instead. You can use [`date.today()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today), or call the [`datetime().date()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date
>>> past = date(2013, 1, 1)
>>> today = date.today()
>>> print today - past
385 days, 0:00:00
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> print now.date() - past
385 days, 0:00:00
```

The result of the subtraction is a [`datetime.timedelta()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta), with `timedelta().seconds` and `timedelta().microseconds` set to `0`, always. The `.days` attribute gives you just that number of days between the dates:

```
>>> print (today - past).days
385
>>> print (now.date() - past).days
385
```

Comment: +1. You can write : `print (now.date() - past).days` if you want to display days only.